# Generic of generics pattern

Tags: swift, generics, inheritance

in Swift

```
class A {}
class A1: A {}
class A2: A {}

class B<Ax: A> {}
class B1: B<A1> {}
class B2: B<A2> {}

class C<Bx: B> {}
class C1: C<B1> {}
class C2: C<B2> {}
```

Here is the idea of what I want to do. It works well to implement `A` and `B` class's. But I can't make it work for `C` class.
It seems that I must specify for `B` what is `A` type:

```
class C<Bx: B<A>> {}
```

But then, `C1` and `C2` doesn't match `C` class inheritance, cause `B1` (aka `B<A1>`) and `B2` (aka `B<A2>`) doesn't inherit from `B<A>`

How can I make it work in Swift ?

Comment: Have you tried `C<Bx: B<Ax: A>>` ?

Comment: @vincrichaud Yes, doesn't work

Comment: I believe using swift generic type could help you achieve this by declaring class C as `C<T>`

Answer (score 0):

This is only really solvable by having `C` be generic over two type parameters.

```
class C<Ax: A, Bx: B<Ax>> {}
class C1: C<A1, B1> {}
class C2: C<A2, B2> {}
```

It is unfortunate having to repeat the subclasses of `A` in the signatures of the subclasses of `C`, but you do at least get compile time checks for the correct inheritance relations you are looking for. For example

```
class C2: C<A1, B2> {} // error
```

will produce the error `'C' requires that 'B2' inherit from 'B<A1>'`.